# this transfer is forbidden by the target device

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am making bluetooth app when i send image to another device having an error
**Transfer is forbidden by the target machine**. I am not using server thread approach to send image.

Here is my Java code

```
public void SendData(){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("image/jpeg");
        String uri = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/All picture/Good morning/" + mesg.getText().toString() + ".jpeg";
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(uri)));
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

Comment: Just a word of advice - I won't even read past anything like "plz" or "thankx" in a question. As soon as I saw those words in your post, I stopped reading, and I won't answer your question, even if I know the answer. Use full words - image you're writing an email to a busy coworker. Your post should be short, but still respectful and professional.

Comment: Ok, I am new here, if you understand my question kindly help me

Comment: Nice job fixing up your post. I don't actually know the answer, now that I've read the problem. But good luck getting an answer, and welcome to Stack Overflow!